# Fastify insists on sending plain text instead of html

Tags: fastify

I cannot understand why this:

```
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'
...
const file = fs.readFileSync(path.join('/path/to/folder', 'index.html'))
reply.headers({ 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8' }).send(file)
```

is resulting in this in my browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html,
            body,
            div,
....
```

What have I done wrong? I've set the content type. And I've also tried `reply.type('text/html')` but same issue...

Answer (score 0):

Can't replicate, here a working snippet:

```js
const fs = require('fs')

const app = require('fastify')({ logger: true })
app.get('/', (request, reply) => {
  const file = fs.readFileSync('./index.html')
  console.log(file)

  reply.type('text/html').send(file)
})

app.listen({ port: 3000 })
```

Note that you should not use `readFileSync`.

Here is a better version:

```js
const fs = require('fs')

const app = require('fastify')({ logger: true })
app.get('/', (request, reply) => {
  const stream = fs.createReadStream('./index.html')
  console.log(stream)

  reply.type('text/html').send(stream)
})

app.listen({ port: 3000 })
```